# Opera and Custom cursor in CSS

Tags: css, opera

Where I normally am verry proud of Opera for implementing everything CSS really correct it seems that implementing a custom cursor with the following line doesn't seem to work

```
cursor:url("../pics/merge.gif");
```

The URL is correct since it works for regular background-image properties.
Works in other browsers, but not in Opera.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a workaround for opera using javascript:

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/customcursor

works ok, tested in opera 11, though I'd recommend usual css approach for other browsers, especially older ie, which are not too fast even without js.

Comment: not the most preferable solution, but if everything else fails this could be the best option. Thx

Comment: Important to note that in Opera the jQuery “fix” does not replace the cursor but merely places an image under the cursor every time it moves; thus you get a double cursor (one of which may be a bit laggy/jumpy).

Comment: plugins.jquery.com doesn't work now, but there are similar solutions:
http://jquery.kidsil.net/custom-cursor/
http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/css/create-custom-cursors-with-javascript-and-css3.html

Answer (score 15):

Opera has not yet added support for that. That line is incorrect though, per the specification a fallback cursor is required. So you have to write e.g.

cursor:url("path/to/cursor"), wait;

(Disclaimer: I work for Opera.)

Comment: You work for opera? Thanks for such a great product. Also, what's the company like? If they ever think of accepting 1 year foreign interns, please do contact me ;)

Answer (score 3):

Opera [doesn't seem to](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/cursor.html) support the url property. It might even [be being removed](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=3559&start=0&st=0&sk=t&sd=a) from the spec (will check that).

Comment: the URL property? You do mean in combination with the cursor? It dftly supports it with background-image...

Answer (score 2):

the js version is really slow. There is also a filesize limit on the image. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/cursor is a good place to read about CSS cursors.