# JavaScript cursor acting odd

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, cursor

### Setup

---

I'm making an HTML page that replaces the cursor with a `div` element. The Javascript is below. The div element is simply `<div id="cursor"/>`.

```
function fixCursor()
{
  var cPos = getCursorPosition();
  cursor.style="top:" + (cPos.y) + "; left:" + (cPos.x) + "; position:fixed; width:16px; height:16px; background-color:#DDDDDD; box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.5); border:2px solid #111111; border-radius:0 100% 100% 100%;";
  return;
}

function getCursorPosition(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var cursor = {x:0, y:0};
    if (e.pageX || e.pageY) {
        cursor.x = e.pageX;
        cursor.y = e.pageY;
    }
    else if (e.screenX || e.ecreenY) {
        cursor.x = e.screenX;
        cursor.y = e.screenY;
    }
    else if (e.x || e.y) {
        cursor.x = e.x;
        cursor.y = e.y;
    }
    else if (e.clientX || e.clientY) {
        var de = document.documentElement;
        var b = document.body;
        cursor.x = e.clientX;
        cursor.y = e.clientY;
    }
    return cursor;
}
```

### Problem

---

This only works on Opera, and shows signs of working on IE, but doesn't show the cursor. On Firefox and Chrome, nothing appears. I haven't tried Safari, as I uninstalled it a while ago, but in my experience, its rendering works alot like Chrome, anyway.

Comment: Is there a reason that you are trying to do this with JavaScript instead of just using the [CSS `cursor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/cursor) property?

Comment: I'm not seeing where you are grabbing the div with var cursor = document.getElementById("cursor"). Did you forget to include that in your example, or?

Comment: @mcculloh I don't understand what you're trying to say...

Comment: @Useless Code Yes, because I don't want a system cursor, I want a custom cursor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, `getCursorPosition` takes an event object, `e`. In `fixCursor`, you are not passing anything in. You should probably make `fixCursor` take an event object as well and pass it through to `getCursorPosition`. Then, in your event handler where you're presumably calling `fixCursor`, pass in the event object passed into your event handler.

Also, you cannot set `style` equal to a string. You can, however, set `style.cssText`.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try it when my laptop recharges >.<

Answer (score 0):

You can add [custom cursors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_URL_values_for_the_cursor_property) with the CSS `cursor` property, all major browsers but Opera [support it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_URL_values_for_the_cursor_property#Compatibility_with_other_browsers) to one extent or another.  If you want it to work in IE you'll need to use a .cur or .ani cursor file, the other browsers support at minimum .cur, .png, .jpg and .gif.

Alternatively [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447038/opera-and-custom-cursor-in-css#answer-5895692) points to a [jQuery plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/customcursor) that might be easier to use than implementing it yourself.

Personally I've never found a situation where I *had* to use a custom cursor, I usually just use a .png `cursor` in my stylesheet and leave a sensible default value for the browsers that don't support .png cursors.

Comment: In this case, it has to be a div element

Answer (score 0):

Are you planning to do this onmousemove? That's a *lot* of overhead. In any case, I see a few problems, but I don't know if fixing them alone will get you a cross-browser solution.

First, let's assume you're triggering this function onmousemove, so you have this in your script:

```
document.onmousemove = fixCursor;
```

You have to have fixCursor() pass an event object to getCursorPosition() like this:

```
function fixCursor(e)
{
  var cPos = getCursorPosition(e);
...
```

And you have to explicitly set each style attribute:

```
cursor.style.cursor = 'none'; // Didn't see you set this
cursor.style.top = cPos.y;
cursor.style.left = cPos.x;
cursor.style.position = "fixed";
```

A quick test showed me that this worked in Firefox but not IE. Setting position to "absolute" got closer in IE, but not in a useful way.

EDIT: Oh, and it appears you're not properly referencing the "cursor" div in your fixCursor() function. Use

```
var cursor = document.getElementById('cursor');
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll try it when my laptop recharges >.<