# setting cursor style in mouseover in Opera

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseover

I am trying to pass value of `status` attribute of an ancor to `window.status`. Below is the code:

```
$('a').hover(function(event){   
    if ($(this).attr('status')) {   
        window.status=$(this).attr('status');   
        return false}  
    },
    function(){
        window.status='';
        return false;
    }
)
```

Yes, I know that it wouldn't work in IE&FF. Lets proceed with Opera. Status passed OK but mouse cursor remains default, not pointer. Inserting

```
$(this).css('cursor','pointer');
```

in mouseover doesnt help. How can mouse cursor be turned to pointer? And why it remains default?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Opera and Custom cursor in CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/447038/opera-and-custom-cursor-in-css)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's [plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/customcursor)

Comment: it seems like A:hover handler blocks customcursor functionality. it shows it's dino over `h2` but not over `a`

Comment: I even not know whether will I use it - too many blinks while it moves down the links, up the links it moves gradually.

Answer (score 0):

Cursor may be "default" because your A's href is empty. Just fill it with "#"

Besides, you can use next cross-browser hack to manipulate the status:

```
<a href="Message: this text will appear in the status bar">link</a>
```

Comment: thanks for the hack. unfortunately I need to have indexable links.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$(this).attr('style', 'cursor:pointer !important')
```

Update:
  remove return false from the methods. That will do it

Comment: then status bar is system one. cursor... it chages to `pointer` very seldom.