# Jquery / css way to set custom cursors which work in Opera (or cross-browser)?

Tags: jquery, cross-browser, cursor, opera, custom-cursor

Opera is known for not supporting cursor url in css. So I tried this:

http://jsfiddle.net/zevH9/

`$("div").css('cursor','url(http://w17.snunit.k12.il/images/big_arrow.png),auto');`

and it won't work. Is there any Opera-specific or cross-browser solution for this, which would work regardless of browser support?

**edit**: I tried to use jquery custom-cursor plugin. It technically works but it lags and flickers awfully. And there is still the default cursor in Opera, together with custom image. Any way to fix this?

http://jsfiddle.net/zevH9/1/

```
function customcursor(element,imgUrl) {
    $('body').append('<img style="position:absolute;display:none;cursor:none;" id="mycursor" src="'+imgUrl+'" />');
    element.css('cursor','none');
    $(element).hover(function() {
        $('#mycursor').show();
    },function() {
        $('#mycursor').hide();      
    });
    $(element).mousemove(function(e){
            $('#mycursor').css('left', e.clientX - 1).css('top', e.clientY + 1);
    });
}
customcursor($('div'),'http://w17.snunit.k12.il/images/big_arrow.png');
```

Comment: It is working for Opera 22...

Comment: the Solution is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/447038/opera-and-custom-cursor-in-css/5895692#5895692